# Parse and add extra data to CKEditor before save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm using the CKEditor.

I need to add text *around* the html outputted by CKEditor (i.e., an opening and closing tag around the html output; not an html tag).

Is there any way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend wrapping the HTML when outputting it, instead of before saving it (if that's what you are doing). Will save you the trouble of ensuring it's not already wrapped when editing the HTML.

Comment: @simshaun - How can I do that?

Comment: Save the HTML output from the editor into the database like normal.  When you go to display it, `echo '<div>'. $html .'</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

you can get the html data within the editor via `.getData()`

Something like this might work for you:

```
 var wrappedOutput = '<div>'+ CKEDITOR.instances.NameOfEditorInstance.getData() +'</div>';
```

Here is a link to the docs pointing to **[.getData()](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#getData)**